# Get path variable id from backend in angular 13

Tags: angular

so i am trying to get the current logged in user's id and I am always getting undefined no matter what.. I tried with paramMap, params, but i can't seem to get why i am not getting the user id in return..

here is the code:

**user entity**

```
export class User {
    id?: number;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    email?: string;
    imageUrl?: string;
    accountType?: string;
}

export class UserLoginDto {
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
  accountStatus?: string;
  oldToken?: string;
}
```

**user service class**

```
export class UserService {
private apiServerUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  }
  public findUserById(userId: number) {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/user/` + userId);
  }
}
```

**user component**

```
 constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
userId;

  getUser(){
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.userService.findUserById(params["id"]).subscribe(response => {
      this.userId = response.id;
      console.log(this.userId);
    });
   });

  }
```

Update: forgot to add my **authentication service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  USER_NAME_SESSION = 'authenticatedUser';
  private url = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  username: string;
  password: string;

  public login(username: string, password: string): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username+":"+password)});
    this.http.get<UserLoginDto>(`${this.url}/login`, {headers}).subscribe(response => {
        this.registerLogin(username,password);
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
});
}

registerLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION, username);
  }
```

Comment: Why are all your class props optional `?`. What does `this.http.get<User>${this.apiServerUrl}/user/ + userId);` return, does the response json even have id? What does the object look like? Where are you calling `getUser()`? You are trying to get id from params `params["id"]` by subscribing to it's changes. Are you sure your component is active to make this call? Where are you even setting the id to params?

Comment: that request should return the id of the current logged in user, response yes has an id property, i called getUser() in ngOnInit(), in my app.routing.module i set a path for this component to 'profile/:id', I am a begginer to angular and just trying to learn how things work..

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing rest of the code. But I think you simply don't have anything in route params to get. You need to add id to params. Maybe on `login()`? So next time you want to get them from params should be there to be used. Or use a service to store user data.

Comment: @JoosepParts Oh yeah i found the issue, you were right my route id param was on another component and not on the actual component i needed, thank you very much !